# Mapbox: Support for loading tiles from .mbtiles in iOS

Tags: ios, mapbox, mbtiles

How can I load tiles from `.mbtiles` on `Mapbox` in iOS? 
I was following this: http://usualcarrot.com/creating-mbtiles-db-for-ios-mapbox-from-hi-res-map-image
Seems this is very old code and I was wondering is there still support for `.mbtiles`